# Warning: file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory'

Tags: symfony

I need help, I don't understand what this error mean! I'm using symfony2 and I'm biggners,

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message
>   'Warning:
>   file_get_contents(C:\wamp\www\teva_com\src\Softivendor\MainBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/index.html.twig):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\teva_com\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php:130
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError(2,
>   'file_get_conten...', 'C:\Program File...', 130, Array) #1 C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\teva_com\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php(130):
>   file_get_contents('C:\wamp\www\tev...') #2 C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\teva_com\app\cache\prod\classes.php(6334):
>   Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getSource('SoftivendorMain...') #3 C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\teva_com\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php(126):
>   Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('SoftivendorMain...') #4 C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\teva_com\vendor\ in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\teva_com\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php
>   on line 166

Could anyone help me and explain this so that I will understand it! 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you use a docker container, the reason for this error might be that you have ran `app/console cache:clear` on your local machine, which in turn (re)generates some cache, specifically paths to view templates.
Which of course generates paths that are pointing to absolute paths of views on your **host** machine.

So try to execute `app/console cache:clear` on your container instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be the command

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

and

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

didn't completely clear the cache folder.